# How to fix Lion 10.7 Apple Webmail "Connection to IMAP server failed"?

Tags: macos, network, server.app

Apple webmail on Lion (10.7) Server is returning a popup error message about 60 seconds after trying to login:

> Connection to imap server failed

or in Dutch:

> Connectie met IMAP server mislukt

Regression:

- Using the same user name and password, while sending and receiving mail works from Mail.app.

This Lion Server:

- runs 10.7.5
- is located behind a NAT router device
- id configured on a non routable 192.168.0.1 IP address
- uses a "Computer Name" and "Host Name" that are identical
- has a "Computer Name" and "Host Name" that are in the form of "host.domain.tld"
- "host.domain.tld" has an A record in public DNS that refers to the public IP address of the NAT router

How to fix this '**Connection to IMAP server failed**' issue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Apple Webmail "Connection to IMAP server failed" error kept re-appearing, I changed `/usr/share/webmail/config/appleoverrides.inc.php` to:

```
$rcmail_config['default_host'] = 'localhost';
//$rcmail_config['smtp_server'] = '%h';
```

#### Idea from

Change in `/usr/share/webmail/config/appleoverrides.inc.php` the value of `rcmail_config['default_host']` from its default `'tls://%h'` to `'tls://macserver.examle.com'`.

source: https://discussions.apple.com/message/16922962